# Why is Chromecast unable to stream this HLS video? "Neither ID3 nor ADTS header was found" / Error NETWORK/315

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, http-live-streaming, google-cast-sdk, hls.js

I'm trying to stream some URLs to my Chromecast through a sender app. They're HLS/m3u8 URLs.

Here's one such example URL: https://qa-apache-php7.dev.kaltura.com/p/1091/sp/109100/playManifest/entryId/0_wifqaipd/protocol/https/format/applehttp/flavorIds/0_h65mfj7f,0_3flmvnwc,0_m131krws,0_5407xm9j/a.m3u8

However they never seem to load on the Chromecast, despite other HLS/m3u8 URLs working ([example of an HLS stream that does work](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/CastVideos/hls/DesigningForGoogleCast.m3u8)).

It's not related to CORS as they indeed have the proper CORS headers.

I notice they have separate audio groups in the root HLS manifest file.

When I hook it up to a custom receiver app, I get the following logs:

[image]

The relevant bits being (I think): Neither ID3 nor ADTS header was found at 0 and cast.player.api.ErrorCode.NETWORK/315 (which I believe is a result of the first)

These are perfectly valid/working HLS URLs. They play back in Safari on iOS and desktop perfectly, as well as VLC.

Is there something I need to be doing (either in my sender app or my receiver app) to enable something like the audio tracks? [The docs seem to indicate something about that](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/mpl/streaming_protocols#http_live_streaming_hls).

I also found this Google issue where a person had a similar issue, but solved it somehow that I can't understand. https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/112277373

How would I playback this URL on Chromecast properly? Am I to do something in code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This already has a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55224639/does-the-chromecast-support-casting-videos-from-reddit-hls-and-dash-videos) but I will add this answer in case someone looks up the exact error message / code.

The problem lies in the `hlsSegmentFormat` which is initialized to `TS` for multiplexed segments but currently defaults to packed audio for HLS with alternate audio tracks.

The solution is to intercept the CAF `LOAD` request and set the correct segment format:

```
const context = cast.framework.CastReceiverContext.getInstance();
const playerManager = context.getPlayerManager();
// intercept the LOAD request
playerManager.setMessageInterceptor(cast.framework.messages.MessageType.LOAD, loadRequestData => {
            loadRequestData.media.hlsSegmentFormat = cast.framework.messages.HlsSegmentFormat.TS;
            return loadRequestData;
});
context.start();
```

Source: Google Cast [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70031250#comment21)

Comment: What's the equivalent in JAVA? I need to do this in an app, but I could not find a way to access the player neither set a message interceptor.

Answer (score 1):

For those who manage multiple video sources in various formats and who don't want to arbitrarily force the HLS fragment format to TS, I suggest to track the error and set a flag that force the format at the next retry (by default, the receiver tries 3 times before giving up).

First, have a global flag to enable the HLS segments format override:

```
setHlsSegmentFormat = false;
```

Then detect the error:

```
playerManager.addEventListener(cast.framework.events.EventType.ERROR, 
  event => {
    if (event.detailedErrorCode == cast.framework.events.DetailedErrorCode.HLS_NETWORK_INVALID_SEGMENT) {
      // Failed parsing HLS fragments. Will retry with HLS segments format set to 'TS'
      setHlsSegmentFormat = true;
    }
  }
);
```

Finally, handle the flag when intercepting the playback request:

```
playerManager.setMediaPlaybackInfoHandler(
  (loadRequest, playbackConfig) => {
    if (setHlsSegmentFormat) {
      loadRequest.media.hlsSegmentFormat = cast.framework.messages.HlsSegmentFormat.TS;
      // clear the flag to not force the format for subsequent playback requests
      setHlsSegmentFormat = false;
    }
  }
);
```

The playback will quickly fail the first time and will succeed at the next attempt. The loading time is a bit longer but the HLS segment format is only set when required.